# Shape of passed values is (1, 32561), indices imply (2, 32561)

Tags: pandas, join

I am trying to join a new columns to pandas after LabelBinariring the column Sex. The `df["sex"].value_counts()` returns

```
 Male      21790
 Female    10771
Name: sex, dtype: int64
```

However when i execute this

```
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
    binarize=LabelBinarizer()
    data_o=df.join(pd.DataFrame(binarize.fit_transform(data["sex"]),
columns=binarize.classes_,index=data.index))
```

I get the error

`Shape of passed values is (1, 32561), indices imply (2, 32561`)

yet sex column is is composed of two type(male and female). How can i fix this. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you do:

```
binarize.fit_transform(data["sex"]).shape
len(binarize.classes_)
```

and see what the outputs are?

Comment: binarize.fit_transform(data["sex"]).shape returns (32561, 1) but len(binarize.classes_) returns 2  why binarize.fit_transform(data["sex"]).shape does not return  (32561, 2) cracks me @ugn

Comment: @onexpeters may be the shape is supposed to be just one column?

Comment: you are right, the column should be one with(0,1 for male and female), thanks for insight.

Comment: @onexpeters if it is the right answer, please accept, thanks